# Is there a way to isolate the condition in an OR conditional statement that failed the test and pass it to another method?

Tags: c#, textbox, conditional-statements

I have an interesting inquiry for you all.

I am working on a C# project and thought it would make a neat addition to have the textboxes change color if the user submit a non-numeric value. I already have an extended Or conditional statement set up that checks for non-numerics, as such:

```
public void catchNonNumeric()
{
   int parsedValue;
   if (!int.TryParse(txtBxStudentInput.Text, out parsedValue) || 
       !int.TryParse(txtBxPCInput.Text, out parsedValue) || 
       !int.TryParse(txtBxStuTourInput.Text, out parsedValue) || 
       !int.TryParse(txtBx203A.Text, out parsedValue) || 
       !int.TryParse(txtBx203F.Text, out parsedValue))
   {
     checker = false;
   }
   else
   {
     checker = true;
   }
}
```

But now I am wondering if there is a way to take the failed condition/textbox in this statement and change its color to show the user where exactly the problem is.

This isn't a dire need, just something I think would be cool! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: using method or Func instead of just the tryparse bool and keep the result of failed test

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a `List<TextBox>` of the controls you want to validate, and then loop over them to test the condition. If one of them fails, set the `checker` to `false` and the `ForeColor` of that one to `Red`:

```
public void CatchNonNumeric()
{
    // Start our checker flag variable to true
    checker = true;

    // Create a list of TextBox controls that we want to validate
    var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> 
        {txtBxStudentInput, txtBxPCInput, txtBxStuTourInput, txtBx203A, txtBx203F};

    // Validate each TextBox
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        int parsedValue;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out parsedValue))
        {
            // Reset the color to black (or whatever the default is) if it passes
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.WindowText);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise set the color to red and our checker flag to false
            checker = false;
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The textbox in WPF will get this by default if you bind to a numeric. You will get the data rejection along with UI styling.

Otherwise you can certainly use Func to delegate a query. The Func takes any number of generics as an input and will provide the output you want (in this case a boolean).

```
var functionDelegate = new Func<string, bool>(text =>
{
    int parsedValue;
    return int.TryParse(text, out parsedValue);
}


//Usage
var isStudentInputNumercic = functionDelegate(txtBxStudentInput.Text);
```